# Dynamically adding Dat.gui elements from array of objects

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

I am trying to extend a dat.gui menu to support multiple datasets as they are added by the user.

The aim is to rebuild the gui when a new dataset is loaded. So in the snippet below, it should add a new slider for each object in the array data.

```
function buildGui() {
  var gui_data = []
  gui = new dat.GUI();

  // data is an array of objects
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // create gui folder for each dataset with name var1
      gui_data.push(gui.addFolder(data[i].var1))

      // add a slider linked to data[i].var2 <- already set as an integer
      gui_data[i].frameno = gui_data[i].add(this,data[i].var2).name('var2');

  }
}
```

The last line raises an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I know that `this` is the wrong object to pass, but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Which is the affected row?

Comment: edited to specify the affected row

Comment: Can you console log gui_data just before the last line and tell us the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the above `data[i].var2` did not exist - I was trying to reference the variable without having created it. Given that data[i].frameNo exists, the version below works.

```
function buildGui() {
  var gui_data = []
  gui = new dat.GUI();

  // data is an array of objects
  data.forEach(function(each,i) {
      // create gui folder for each dataset with name var1
      gui_data.push(gui.addFolder(data[i].var1))

      // add a slider linked to data[i].var2 <- already set as an integer
      gui_data[i].frameno = gui_data[i].add(each,'frameNo').name('var2');

  }
}
```